# GeoPandas categorical colormap

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to plot with Geopandas points with colors based on categorical data. I'm trying to assign the tab10 colormap to them but am being unable to do so. Below is my code and what I'm getting, which is not the tab10 colors:

```py
dfs_issues.plot(ax=ax, zorder=2, label=label, markersize=50, marker='*', column='issue', categorical=True, cmap='tab10', legend=True)
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your number of categories is 3, it is output correctly. Out of 10 colors, the first, middle, and last colors are output. If you want 3 colors in sequence, you have to take a different approach.

```
import seaborn as sns
cmap_tab10 = sns.color_palette("tab10", 10)
cmap_new = sns.color_palette([cmap_tab10[0], cmap_tab10[1], cmap_tab10[2]], as_cmap=True)
dfs_issues.plot(ax=ax, zorder=2, label=label, markersize=50, marker='*', column='issue', categorical=True, cmap=cmap_new, legend=True)
```